# Simular transicion del ViewPager con fragmentos pero en actividades

Tags: android, android-intent

Suponiendo que tenemos dos actividades, A y B.

Quiero que al pulsar un elemento (por ejemplo un botón) de la actividad A cambie a la actividad B simulando el efecto que hay implementado en el ViewPager al cambiar de un fragmento a otro, como que se desliza una actividad hacia un lado y la otra aparece seguidamente.

Ese efecto es lo que me gustaría simular, pero en vez de deslizando o usando tabs que ocurra al pulsar cualquier view y que sea entre dos actividades y no dos fragmentos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacerlo con

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_translate, R.anim.slide_left_translate);
```

También con esto:

```
Slide slide= new 
slide.setDuration(1000);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);


Slide slide= new 
slide.setDuration(1000);
getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
```

Escribiendo esas lineas de código en actividad A y actividad B

Pero no si si es que estoy utilizando ese código de arriba mal o se hace de otra manera o simplemente no se puede hacer entre dos actividades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De entrada

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

De salida

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Animaciones

left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="50%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: La linea de código de entrada la estoy escribiendo debajo del setContentView(LayoutActividad)  pero no hace absolutamente nada =/ también he probado a escribirlo antes del setContentView() y tampoco hace nada u.u''

Comment: Vale ya lo he conseguido, tenía que escribirlo justamente después del startActivity(); Gracias !

Comment: el método override se pone después del finish(), intentalo

Comment: genial!!!, muchas gracias

Comment: Una última pregunta, a partir de que API funciona ese método?

Comment: Según la documentación, API 5

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo había estado mirando y me parecía raro por eso pregunté xD ahora lo probare en la API 16 y ya comento si funciona.

Comment: de entrada a que te refieres, si tienes Actividad A, B entiendo que (entrada) es la B donde se tiene que poner el código en onCreate()?

Comment: cuando abres un activity se pone antes de start activity y cuando la cierras lo pones despues del finish

Answer (score 1):

Complemento la respuesta de @Nicol_Israel_Olvera_Acosta

Transiciones entre actividades usando `overridePendingTransition(anim_entrada,ani_salida)`

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityB.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

En la `ActivityB` cuando se cierre, realizar la transición inversa

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

}
```

Comment: Es correcto, yo tuve que ponerlo también en su momento para hacerlo a la inversa. Gracias !